# WrapPanel unnecessarily moving items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox that needs to show more than one item per row if there's room for it. I've tried to use WrapPanel as common solution but it's moving all items to the first row. This is the XAML I'm using.

```
<Border CornerRadius="0.5" Background="#FEFEFE" BorderThickness="0" Margin="20">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" Color="#000000" Opacity="14" ShadowDepth="0" Direction="0" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <ListBox x:Name="listaAtletas" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid MinWidth="350" Height="100">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Imagem}" Width="40" Height="40" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Grid.Column="1" >
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Nome}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nascimento}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Modalidades}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Column="2" >
                            <Button x:Name="EditButton" Content="E" Width="20" Height="20" />
                            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Content="X" Width="20" Height="20" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Border>
```

The ListBox if filled dynamically after reading a file. Is there something wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: HorizontalScrollBarVisibility should be Disabled

Comment: I can't believe it's just this. It worked perfectly, can you answer the question so I can mark as solution?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property to `Disabled` instead of `Hidden`:

```
<ListBox ... ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    ...
</ListBox>
```